# Ionic File Opener - Detect when file is closed

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using Ionic and Capacitor to download a PDF and then open it in the default PDF reader of my smartphone.
My method looks like that :

```
import { Directory, Filesystem } from "@capacitor/filesystem";
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

getReceiptPDF({ pathParams: { receiptID: props.receipt.receiptID } }).then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 200) {

        // Custom method using Filesystem to download the file in the generic Documents folder of the smartphone)
        downloadFileMobile(response, props.receipt.receiptID + ".pdf"); 

        Filesystem.getUri({
            directory: Directory.Documents,
            path: props.receipt.receiptID + ".pdf"
        }).then((getUriResult) => {
            const path = getUriResult.uri;
            console.debug("PATH : " + path);
            FileOpener.open(path, 'application/pdf')
            .catch((error) => {
                console.debug(error);
            })
        });
    }
})
```

It works well, but now I wanna trigger a method when my file is closed, but I don't see any callback for that in the File Opener documentation.

What can I do to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Capacitor App](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app) plugin for this, e.g.:

```js
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

const waitForResume = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    App.addListener('appStateChange', async (state) => {
      if (state.isActive) {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
};
```